How do I prove continuity of functions defined with domain as a quotient space (in particular, the Möbius band)
Suppose I have the Möbius band defined as the quotient $ M=I\times I / \sim $, where $\sim$ is the generated equivalence relation from the relation given as $(0,y) \sim (1,1-y)$. What are some methods I can use to construct continuous functions from it to other topological spaces?
Very trivially, of course, I can easily define any constant function, all of which are continuous.
But, suppose for instance,  I wanted to prove continuity for a map $f: M \to M$  which maps each point $ (\overline{x},\overline{y}) = (\overline{x},\frac12) $ which essentially can be thought of as collapsing the möbius strip into the circle inside.
How would I go about it? I'm completly lost here...

Judging by the (or rather, a) version of this question you deleted, you already know about the universal property of the quotient. I think it would be a good exercise for you to use for showing your $f$ is continuous.

The universal property allows us to prove continuity of functions from the quotient sets from continuity of functions on the pre quotient set, provided the continous function of pre quotient set is what the quotient is based off of. However it's unclear to me how that's usable at all here @Ben Steffan

Okay, big hint: Consider the function $f'\colon I \times I \to M$, $f'(x, y) = (x', 1 / 2)$. Can you do it now?

I mean presuming f' is continous it is quite easy to apply the universal property but how do you know that f' is continous to begin with? @BenSteffan

Okay, big hint 2: Consider $f''\colon I \times I \to I \times I$, $f''(x, y) = (x, 1/2)$. For this map you should have no problem verifying continuity. Think about how to recover your $f$ from this.

Okay that solves it. Thank you @BenSteffan

With respect to the title: the same way you do for piecewise-defined functions: First, verify continuity inside each piece (i.e., on the maximal cells in the cell decomposition of the quotient) which usually is "inspect the function definition".  Then for each boundary between pieces, verify continuity at those boundaries (i.e. on the lower-dimensional cells identified by the quotient, check transverse continuity, usually recursively, checking interiors then boundaries at each dimension).  So here, check the interior of $I \times I$, then ${0} \times (0,1)$, then at $(0,0)$ and $(0,1)$.

@EricTowers sure that’s doable here but really that’s not ideal and I wouldn’t really encourage that. Ben’s suggestion via universal property is much better and also what we use theoretically and frankly, practically as well.
